# "Recently viewed" list views

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, contact, list-view, tab

In the Contacts tab, annoyingly, there are 2 standard list views: (1) Recently Viewed and (2) Recently Viewed CONTACTS . Most of you wouldn't have even noticed this. For list view number (2), can we choose which columns to show? If not, can we hide list view number (2)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so. [This](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DXKUQA4) is a helpful discussion to detail the difference between the two and the lack of editing you can do on either.